# How can I create a nav bar with a repeat image inside?

Tags: css, navbar

I have a image, and I would like to creat a nav bar with a css reapeat css.. How can I do that?

I tried my css:

```
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('includes/img/menu-bg.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I dont know How can I create a nav bar inside this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it in the nav bar or as the body background? If you want it in the nav bar it would look something more like this:

```
<style>
  nav {
    background: url(includes/img/menu-bg.gif) repeat-x;
  }
</style>
```

You don't need the quotation marks around the file. It isn't a string, it is a path. Also, get in the habit of using an images folder called just that; images. And I would question if a gif is really the best file type for most images on the web.

Comment: Ohh Thanks.. So for using this, I have have to do <div class="nav"... Right?

Comment: If you did that then where I wrote nav, you would write .nav. The way I wrote it is using html5 semantics where in your HTML it would be just <nav>.